# Find longest slices of an array that contain distinct values

Tags: arrays, fortran, slice, partitioning

I have a very long one-dimensional array of positive integers. Starting from one end, I need to find the longest slices/chunks of the array that have values that are at-least one number away from all the constituents of that slice.

i.e., I want to make a partitioning of the array (starting from the left) such that each partition contains elements that are more than one unit away from all the other elements in that partition.

Eg:

1. [1,1,9,5,3,8,7,4,1,2] -> [1],[1,9,5,3],[8],[7,4,1],[2]
2. [1,5,9,1,3,6,4,2,7,0] -> [1,5,9],[1,3,6,4],[2,7,0]

Bellow, I've written a little code in Fortran that will let me find the first such point of recurrence of a previous value.

- mask is a LOGICAL array
- array is the array in question
- n is the length of the array

I can easily extend this to find the full partitioning.

```
mask = .FALSE.

DO i = 1,n

    k = array(i)

    IF ( mask(k) ) THEN
        PRINT*, i
        EXIT
    ELSE
        mask(k-1 : k+1) = .TRUE.
    END IF

END DO
```

So my question is, is there a better way (alorithm) to do this? When I say better, I mean speed. I don't mind a memory cost.

Comment: @d_1999 Oh, what I want is a partitioning such that each slice only has numbers that are more than 1 away from any other constituent of that slice.

Comment: If you do not require a streaming solution, then a second array of the deltas can be computed, and then break the (output) array at the points where you have the zeros in the delta array. Getting vectorised code for the deltas should easy with -O3 or some pragma-like !DIR? SIMD  or !?OMP SIMD (OpenMP) are easy. Then the mask can still be used to show where the zero are at. It depends on how big a very long array is (?), but you say memory is not an issue... You should be able to be bandwidth limited on the vectorised delta part. The mask can also be an integer to keep track of array subsection

Comment: Just some thoughts: In your first example are you allowed `9` and `8` to appear in the same slice? Should it not be `[1],[1,9,3],[8],[7,4,1],[2]`? Also, this follows your rule of *from the left*. In a case `[1,1,9,3,8,10,5,1]` would you want `[1],[1,9,3],[8,10,5,1]` (left) or would you want to pick up the longer maximum slice `[1],[1,9],[3,8,10,5,1]`.

Comment: @Steve Sorry!! Thanks for catching that. Fixed it. And I need it to be from the left, not the longest; althought that would be an interesting problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it could look something like this...

```
DO i = 1,n-1
  Delta(I) = array(I+1) - array(I)
ENDDO

iMask = 0
WHERE(ABS(Delta) < 2) iMask =1
ALLOCATE(splits(SUM(iMask)))

K=0
DO I = 1, n-1
  IF(iMask(I) == 0) CYCLE
  K = K +1
  Splits(K) = I 
ENDDO

!... DEALLOCATE(Splits)
```

Then just print out the data between the splits values, which could be off by a count, and you may also need to do something for the Nth point, so it depends a bit on your implementation and whether your delta is "too the next point" or "from the last point".

In this case I used imask as an integer rather than a logical so I could use SUM.

Comment: I did think about this, but I'll have to find deltas at all 'shifts'. Yours is at a shift of 1 unit. This will only give me nearest neighbour collisions. This will give a 'first' partitioning. I don't know if all that will make it better or worse. I guess I'll have to implement both and check.

Comment: You can still have a LOGICAL array and use COUNT to do the same job as SUM.

Comment: Thanks @physkets on the Intel site under sum it inky mentioned "Internet, real or complex" and I have not looked at the bit level. I could probably use Union/map with a logical if I had thought about it, but for the project I am working on I needed integer anyhow.

Comment: @physkets I see now that it is also all member, and not just the nearest. So the vector friendly layout will not get you too far. The only think I can offer is whether mask((k-1):(k+1)) may have less operations in some vector sense than the three seperate mask operations. One option would be if the range of number is small, then a seperate mask for each value would allow using the IAND operation which is elemental. Maybe that would help?

Comment: Thanks, I 've changed the code as you suggested. I'm doing all this specifically for times when the numbers are huge...

Answer (score 0):

My initial reaction is the naive approach:

- save index bounds on the partition you're currently expanding (`partitionNumber` from `iStart` to `iEnd`)
- Take the next point with index `iEnd+1` and loop from `iStart` to `iEnd` testing that the candidate point is not within 1 of the current members
- If the candidate fails the inclusion test, start it in its own partition by resetting `iStart` and incrementing  `partitionNumber`
- Increment `iEnd`.

If you're expecting the partitions to mostly be quite short then this should be pretty quick. If you're expecting long chains of increasing or decreasing integers you could save the `min` and `max` of values in the partition include a quick test to see if your candidate is outside the range.

I've not tested this and my fortran might be a bit rusty, but I think it represents the above algorithm.

```
partitionNumber = 1
iStart = 1
iEnd = 1
iCandidate = iEnd + 1
arrayMember(iStart) = partitionNumber
DO WHILE (iCandidate <= N)
    DO j = iStart,iEnd
        IF ( ABS(array(iCandidate)-array(j)) < 2 )
            partitionNumber = partitionNumber + 1
            iStart = iCandidate
            EXIT
        END IF
    END DO
    arrayMember(iCandidate) = partitionNumber
    iEnd = iEnd + 1
    iCandidate = iEnd + 1
END DO
```

Operating on your two examples, I would hope it to return `arrayMember` with entries

1. `[1,1,9,5,3,8,7,4,1,2] -> [1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5]` (represents `[1],[1,9,5,3],[8],[7,4,1],[2]`)
2. `[1,5,9,1,3,6,4,2,7,0] -> [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]` (represents `[1,5,9],[1,3,6],[4,2,7,0]`)

I'm not entirely sure I understand how you would extend your version to all partitions, but this might save on defining `mask` of size `MAX(array)`?

Comment: I'm guessing this will take longer than the sample code that I posted. In my case, I do not have to calculate differences everytime. Otherwise, it looks the same. Is that not so?

Comment: @physkets I think the approach is different: your code operates to check one slice, and for every slice you're defining a mask of bools, length `MAX(array)` to block out integers, which you have to move about in, assign `.TRUE.` to values and then reset when you start checking the next partition. Can't comment on which approach will be quicker, but I think the approaches are sufficiently different to merit testing both (if my code actually compiles with minimal changes!)

Comment: @physkets You're probably right though. As I said, this was my naive initial thought, and I was a bit confused by your code with the `mask(array(i))` which I now get